# Execute interval callback after every 5th call

Tags: javascript

I have an interval running every 6 seconds on my page; it populates a bunch of data really nicely.

However, there is one piece of data that is only updated from the DB every 30 seconds. So, I want to wait to execute this callback because if it executes beforehand, it wipes everything out.

My code below waits 30 seconds and then checks. What I'd like is the opposite: Check immediately and then wait 30 seconds before checking again.

I feel like my code is cloogy below and there's a much more elegant solution (though I don't think a do/while loop fits the bill). Am I wrong?

```
counter = 0;
maxCounts = 5;

function callbackForInterval(){
    if(counter === maxCounts){
        if({data hasn't changed}){
            // wipe everything out!!!
        }else{
            // do some other stuff
        }
        counter = 0;
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Thanks for any helpful hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the remainder operator (`%`).

```
var counter = 0;
function callbackForInterval)( {
    if (counter++ % 5 === 0) {
        // This bit only runs every 5 iterations
    }
}
```

That *will* run the code on the first iteration. To run it only starting with the 5th, change the post-increment to a pre-increment.

**Live Example:**

```js
var counter = 0;

function callbackForInterval() {
  if (counter++ % 5 === 0) {
    snippet.log("big tick");
    // This bit only runs every 5 iterations
  } else {
    snippet.log("little tick");
  }
}
var timer = setInterval(callbackForInterval, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
  snippet.log("done");
  clearInterval(timer);
}, 30000);
snippet.log("(stops after 30 seconds)");
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: I added `var` to the above, because unless you're declaring that `counter` variable somewhere, your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).